# stacking images that are contained in separated divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

**see here: http://jsfiddle.net/hPC48/13/**

I don't get my page to work (didn't manage it with z-index, too):

[image]

But the images should be **stacked** (no floating) as shown here:

[image]

Markup:

```
<div id="snapshots">
    <div title="2001">
        <img src="0.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div title="2002">

    </div>
    <div title="2003">
        <img src="3.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Next, I build the navigation (black tiles):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ul = $('<ul />');

    $('#snapshots > div').each(function() {
        $('<li />')
        .text($(this).attr('title'))
        .click(function() {
            console.log("clicked!");
        })
        .appendTo(ul);
    });

    ul.insertBefore($('#snapshots div').first());
```

Last, the container div's are positioned **absolute**:

```
$('#snapshots > div').each(function() {
    var index = $(this).index() - 1;
    var li = $('#snapshots li').eq(index);
    var pos = li.offset();
    var w = li.outerWidth();

    $(this).css("position", "absolute");
    $(this).css("left", pos.left);
    $(this).css("width", w);
});
```

Supplement:

```
#snapshots {
    height: 240px;
}

#snapshots ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 24px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#snapshots li {
    display: inline;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 16px;
    margin: 0px 2px 0px 0px;
    background-color: #1E242B;
    color: #e7e7e7;
}

#snapshots li:hover {
    background-color: #3C464D;
}

#snapshots > div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 400px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Roger

Comment: try adjusting your index: `$(this).index()` to `$('#snapshots > div').index(this)`. Other than that post code your code on "jsfiddle" to help us out!

Comment: Roger, without seeing the current CSS I'm having a hard time visualizing a solution. My sense is that you are pushing too much work to JS. Even if there will be dynamic content, you can probably simply add/remove/toggle classes or place new/changed content in areas already styled by CSS and the various elements will "snap" into place because of the CSS rules that apply.

Comment: Agreed, this is not answerable without seeing the CSS, as the issue is most likely a problem with overflow somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This version of your code has the images all on top of one another: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hPC48/.

But, if I make your yearly tabs be inline (so they display like tabs), then the images are not on top of one another in this version: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hPC48/12/ because you're positioning the images to be under each tab (not all in the same place).

My jsFiddle represents my best attempt to reproduce what you've described.  If it's not what you meant, then please correct/clarify the jsFiddle so everyone can see more exactly what you're asking about.

Comment: thank you. but removing one image and adding styles for #snapshots > div point to the fact that the #snapshot div's are brought to front: http://jsfiddle.net/hPC48/13/

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by setting the z-index on div's that contain an image:

```
$('#snapshots > div').each(function() {
     var index = $(this).index() - 1;
     var li = $('#snapshots li').eq(index);
     var pos = li.offset();
     var w = li.outerWidth();

     $(this).css("position", "absolute");
     $(this).css("left", pos.left);
     $(this).css("width", w);

     $(this)
     .has('img')
     .css("z-index", "999");
});
```